# How to collect money subscription fees for pay content?

Tags: payment

I have a client who has content that he wants to publish on the web (and potentially for iPad).  He wants the viewer to pay to subscribe for the content.

Is there a service out there I can integrate with to for handling the accounts and collecting the monthly subscription fee (using credit cards or something else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several services out there that can help you with this - Recurly (where I work), Chargify, CheddarGetter, Spreedly, etc. These services handle the recurring billing aspect, customer management, email communication, following up with failed payments, etc. You'll also need a payment gateway (to process the cards) and a merchant account (for the payment gateway to deposit the funds into).

Authorize.net and PayPal both have recurring billing features, but the logic for upgrading/downgrading accounts is not there or difficult to use, and you'll still need to handle customer communication for failed payments and other actions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a payment gateway here, which will be responsible for handling the transaction between your site and the many different payment networks. There are a lot of operations happening in between, so you might want to check out the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_gateway) article for a step by step information on that.

We personally use [authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/) in our company for many of its advantages, some of which are:

- It has an API that makes it easy to integrate with any language.
- It is a trusted brand already, proven by the number of merchants that use them.
- It is secure.
- It provides the service with a reasonable price.

Answer (score 0):

Most of major payment gateway providers do support recurring billing or subscription plans, paypal,authorize.net etc, most of the time you have to log in to your account admin console and configure a plan, and send the payment plan id with the payment request to the payment gateway. some payment gateway providers, like Braintree supports to create recurring billing plans dynamically and assign users to that plan at the run time it self, how ever it's always better to go for a local payment gateway provider or a payment gateway which provides low fees, if your preferred payment gateway provider is not supporting recurring billing anther options is to store cc details on the server and and handle it your self but it's a great risk to store cc details on the server, and you will have to follow PCI standards and it's hard.